# Temporarily pull up vinyl deck plank

Tags: deck

I have a vinyl deck and need to temporarily pull up the plank adjacent to the exterior wall and put it back afterwards. Is this easy or hard to do and, if it's possible, how do I do it?

[image: vinyl deck 1]
[image: vinyl deck 2]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular product, but it looks like each plank contains three tread strips separated by a filler strip that probably hides the fasteners.  I'm guessing that the fill strips snap out.  The edge is protected by an angle piece, which would need to come off, and the big button may be a snap-on screw cover.  The post for the railing sits on top of the first and second planks, so that would need to be removed.

Comment: Something like that, or fasteners from below. At any rate, a brand name would be very helpful.

Comment: @isherwood Deck was here when I bought the house so I don't know the brand name and can't find any branding on the exposed parts.

Comment: @fixer1234 I think you're right about the fill strips. Before getting the planks off, I have to figure out how to take the posts off. I lifted off the caps of the posts and there is a metal post in the middle. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to get the horizontal rails out of the vinyl posts (post covers). I might have to lift the entire assembly (vinyl posts & rails) off the metal posts in one piece – not sure yet.